# Kubuntu not showing eth0

Tags: networking, kubuntu, ethernet

I just installed Kubuntu 12.04.2 and do not have an internet connection.

I also cannot access the Desktop and only have the terminal. When I enter `xlcock` I get `Error: Can't open display:`. I believe this is because I do not have the correct drivers and need to download them ... using the internet which I can't access.

So here's what's going on ... `ifconfig` gives:

---

```
lo         Link ecap: Local Loopback
           inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
           RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overrruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overrruns:0 frame:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
           RX bytes:1296 (1.2 KB) TX bytes:1296 (1.2 KB)
```

```
wlan0      Link encap: Ethernet HWaddr 68:17:29:58:49:4a
           UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
           RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overrruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overrruns:0 frame:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

---

`lspci -nnk` gives:

---

```
07:00.0 Network Controller [0280] Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
        Subsystem: Intel Coporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN [8086:4062]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0d:00.0 Ethernet Controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:fa77]
```

---

I believe this means that it is using the ethernet connection but thinks it is a wireless connection.

`sudo lshw -class network` gives:

---

*-network

description: Wireless interface

product: Centrino Wireless=N 2230

...

*network UNCLAIMED

description: Ethernet controller

product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet

---

I want to get the internet working so I can fix the GPU driver, etc. but I can't seem to get it working even though I have my ethernet cable plugged in (and I'm sure it is working).

Comment: What do `ifconfig -a` and `lspci | grep -i ether` say?

Comment: I will update with the full text ... I am having to write it instead of copy/paste, but if it will help I'll put up the full output.

Comment: Your wifi interface is pulled up, but the wired one (AR8161) has no driver loaded. Run `lspci -nnk` and include the relevant part in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment, but I think that wlan0 is not configured(no inet address shown in ifconfig result). what do you have for it in /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: There should be something like "auto wlan0"
"iface wlan0 inet dhcp (or static)"

Comment: There is nothing for wlan0 ... only `lo`. Should I put it in? If so, how do I go about configuring it once I put it in?

Comment: yes add these two lines and run sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart or else reboot.